# Win Universal: UnauthorizedAccessException opening new stream for writing

Tags: c#, async-await, win-universal-app

A customer is reporting an issue with the following code:

```
public static async Task<Stream> CreateAsync(string path)
        {
            StorageFolder folder = await Directory.GetFolderAsync(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
            StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(Path.GetFileName(path), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            return await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
        }
```

The exception they are getting is:

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))            at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)            at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)            at
>   System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions..<OpenStreamForWriteAsyncCore.>d__5.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>              at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.IO.WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions..<OpenStreamForWriteAsyncCore>d__5.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---            at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)            at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)            at MyApp.IO.File.<CreateAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

I am unable to recreate the issue myself so suspect its a threading issue but I'm completely at a loss as to how OpenStreamForWriteAsyncCore can throw this exception if the line before succeeds. Any suggestions what I may be doing wrong?

Comment: If more than one thread tries to open the same file exception will be thrown. It has to be  synchronous

Comment: You can only create files in directories that you ask permission for in your appxmanifest.

Comment: Or use FolderPicker to get directory access. @Daz Eddy, - that's the basics and it's realy too much threads about it

Comment: Thing is: The line that creates the file doesn't throw so I must have access to the folder. Likewise, if the file already exists and is locked by another thread then it is the line that recreates the file that should throw. This problem is almost like the line to open the stream is trying to access the file before the previous line has finished created the file (!!?)

Comment: No. What actually happening in this line (StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(Path.GetFileName(path), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting), if file is already exists it will replace the file. But if other thread has created the file and tried open the stream exception will be thrown right?

Comment: I guess it is plausible for the following to happen: thread 1 creates, thread 2 recreates, thread 1 opens, thread 2 fails to open. I don't think that's happening but I'll need some way to make the function atomic to be sure

Comment: This also might be possible-> thread 1 creates. Thread 2 recreates. Thread 1 tries to open the file but it is replaced.  So exception throws. You have to do syncronously.  Use lock to create and to do  file operation or use semaphore to do file operation then release it when operation is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This also might be possible-> thread 1 creates. Thread 2 recreates. Thread 1 tries to open the file but it is replaced. So exception throws. You have to do syncronously. Use lock to create and to do file operation or use semaphore to do file operation then release it when operation is done.

So better solution is to do it synchronously. Either use lock or semaphore. Here post the solution with semaphore.

```
SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

public static async Task<Stream> CreateAsync(string path)
{
    StorageFile file;
    try
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        StorageFolder folder = await Directory.GetFolderAsync(Path.GetDirectoryName(path));
        file= await folder.CreateFileAsync(Path.GetFileName(path), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }
    finally
    {
        semaphore.Release();
        return await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: It turns out the problem was indeed re-entry while the method was in progress. I didn't use this exact code sample to fix my problem as I used Stephen Toub's AsyncSemaphore class(http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx) but the essence is the same. Also, with the help of some extra logging, I was able to determine code higher up the stack that would benefit from semaphores in order to prevent reading of the file whilst it is being saved.